# Proguard error when signing an apk

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, proguard

I am trying to sign an apk. But when I do, I got this error from proguard

App works perfectly when debugging from usb but when I want to deploy it, everything breaks as you can see. I know it has something to do with the libraries but I don't know how to fix it. These are libraries I am using and they are in "libs" folder:

commons-io-2.4.jar
junrar-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
RootTools-3.4.jar

```
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractLayeredFileProvider
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.FileProvider
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.BaseBlock: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.BlockHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.EAHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.FileHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.MacInfoHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.MainHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.MarkHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.SubBlockHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.rarfile.UnixOwnersHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.testutil.ExtractArchive: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileType
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileType getType()' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileName getName()' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileName
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileName
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractLayeredFileProvider
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.FileProvider
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.Capability
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.LayeredFileName
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileType
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileProvider: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileName
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemManager getFileSystemManager()' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileName getRootName()' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.UriParser
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemManager
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileName
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject getFileFromCache(org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileName)' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'void putFileToCache(org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject)' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'void holdObject(java.lang.Object)' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileName getName()' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced method 'void closeCommunicationLink()' in class com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RARFileSystem: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.Capability
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RandomAccessContentAccess: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RandomAccessContentAccess: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RandomAccessContentAccess: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.util.RandomAccessMode
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RandomAccessContentAccess: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileContent
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.RandomAccessContentAccess: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.RandomAccessContent
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolume: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolume: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.util.RandomAccessMode
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolume: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileContent
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolume: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolume: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.RandomAccessContent
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolumeManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: com.github.junrar.vfs2.provider.rar.VFSVolumeManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileName
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: there were 143 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to program class members.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
Error:ProGuard: [OpenIt - File Explorer]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How should I write the whole project properties and how ?